# Высота UILabel в зависимости от размера текста

Tags: xcode, swift, label, autolayout

Внутри ScrollView находятся несколько `UILabel`, в которые приходит строка из `JSON`. Есть вот такой кусок (с предметами):

[image: UILabel]

В него приходит иногда довольно длинная строка, которая не помещается по высоте. Получается вот так:

[image: UILabel с данными]

Остальные предметы не отображаются.

Подскажите, куда копнуть?
Я перепробовал много идей, например, с использованием `extension` к `UILabel`, но что-то не взлетает.
Возможно, какие-то проблемы с констрейнами в данном конкретном случае, но я не уверен.

Буду благодарен за любые варианты :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки дошел сам.

`extension` работает. Просто для констрейна высоты надо было выставить >=, и тогда все растягивается как надо.